# How do I retreive the first bit of a number (or specific bits) without a mask?

Tags: python, c++, optimization, bit-manipulation

Assuming we're working in 16bits

Lets say I have an algorithm that retrieves the signs from a very large list of numbers.
I could do something like

```
sign=(number>0)-(number<0)
```

but I want to be more efficient than this.

The very first bit of the integer(or float) should store its sign value. How could i tell the computer to retrieve only the first bit of my number?
I have tried this:

```
sign=number>>16
```

This works well but I really want to just read 1 bit without doing any sort of operation at all.

Storing this type of data is much easier. We execute this code for every entry and store it as a binary number.

```
data= (data<<1) + sign
```

Retrieving this data is more complicated however.
Lets say i want to read the first or last n bits of my number.
We could do something like

```
last_10_bits= number & (0b000001111111111)
first_10_bits= (number & (0b111111111100000))>>5
```

This works nice, but what if i want to read every second bit and store it in 8bit ?

```
bits_2nd = number % (-0b010101010101010)
```

This doesn't work! I have a bunch of zeroes in the middle of my number I cannot get rid of without using an algorithm. This is such a long way of doing something very easy.

In essence, is there a way to make the pointer read only specific bits in my data?
Is there any other language that allows this or is this only achievable by writing machine code?
I know I'm overthinking this, I'm not actually making an algorithm for this, it's just an easy way of asking a difficult question.

Comment: You're overthinking this. Use the mask and let the optimizing compiler do it's job.

Comment: The cpu operates on bytes, not bits. So no, no way, not even in assembly language. You have to mask and shift. To help with that there's a book called Bit Twiddling Hacks or smth like that.

Comment: Removing zeroes from the middle is possible with the [pext](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pext) instruction

Comment: to get the sign bit of a 16-bit number you'll use `number >> 15` instead of `sign=number>>16`. And as said, CPUs can't load single bits. In fact many CPUs like DEC Alpha couldn't even load a value smaller than the register size. And you'll also have to load a whole word from RAM. There's no way to read even a single byte from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been said in the comments, you *really* should just let the compiler to its job and use the mask. And still, you will have to move the bits manually if you want to remove gaps like in your last example.

If you do still want to access individual bits, you can use a bitfield structure:

```
struct S {
  unsigned int b : 3; // This field is 3 bits long
  unsigned int c : 1; // This one is a single bit
};
```

Then you can access the single fields:

```
struct S mystruct;
mystruct.b = ...;
mystruct.c = ...;
```

(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field)

---

As an alternative, you could also use C++'s [std::bitset](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/), which provides a nice interface where you don't even have to define the struct manually. Just like before, shifts will still be present in the generated machine code.

---

This is not just an issue with the programming language, but with the CPU itself. The most that a language or library will be able to offer is a nice interface on top of the shifts&masks that the CPU needs to use to extract the individual bits